# Increasing efficiency of Python copying large datasets

Tags: python, performance, random-forest

I'm having a bit of trouble with an implementation of random forests I'm working on in Python. Bare in mind, I'm well aware that Python is not intended for highly efficient number crunching. The choice was based more on wanting to get a deeper understanding of and additional experience in Python. I'd like to find a solution to make it "reasonable".

With that said, I'm curious if anyone here can make some performance improvement suggestions to my implementation. Running it through the profiler, it's obvious the most time is being spent executing the list "append" command and my dataset split operation. Essentially I have a large dataset implemented as a matrix (rather, a list of lists). I'm using that dataset to build a decision tree, so I'll split on columns with the highest information gain. The split consists of creating two new dataset with only the rows matching some critera. The new dataset is generated by initializing two empty lista and appending appropriate rows to them.

I don't know the size of the lists in advance, so I can't pre-allocate them, unless it's possible to preallocate abundant list space but then update the list size at the end (I haven't seen this referenced anywhere).

Is there a better way to handle this task in python?

Comment: Efficient number crunching in Python can be done using Numpy and Scipy.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your codes, it is really hard to give any specific suggestions since optimisation is code-dependent process that varies case by case. However there are still some general things:

1. review your algorithm, try to reduce the number of loops. It seems
   you have a lot of loops and some of them are deeply embedded in
   other loops (I guess).
2. if possible use higher performance utility modules such as itertools
   instead of naive codes written by yourself.
3. If you are interested, try PyPy (http://pypy.org/), it is a
   performance-oriented implementation of Python.